# Is this a mistake in a Torah scroll or intended decoration?

Tags: hebrew, safrus, text, torah-writing

In the following pictures, is the superscript addition a correction or intended decoration?  Are corrections like this kosher?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it isn't a decoration -- the extra word is in the verse (Gen 33:11)

Comment: I realize the word is supposed to be there.  By decoration I meant that the word was superscript rather than written inline.  Or was it mistakenly not written the first time and added later?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a valid way of inserting missing words, as the Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh De'ah in  [סימן רעו - דין תלית הדלוג](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_40.html#HtmpReportNum0006_L2) Paskens:

> **א:** טָעָה וְדִלֵּג תֵּבָה אוֹ יוֹתֵר, יָכוֹל לִתְלוֹתָהּ בֵּין הַשִּׁיטִין אֲבָל לֹא בָּרֶוַח שֶׁבֵּין דַּף לְדַף.‏

If he erred and missed a word or more, he can hang it between the lines, but he may not put it in the space between the columns.